# ROS how to use values from one callback function to another

Tags: python, ros, subscriber, rospy

Sorry, English isn't my mother tongue. I hope you'll understand my question correctly.

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS Melodic. I’m trying to take data from `mapCallback` and `odometryCallback` functions and use these values in `SampleTree` function. When I run the code a have below, I want to return frontCones array as a result, but my output is empty array. How can I make the `SampleTree` function take values, published in `mapCallback` and `odometryCallback` functions and use this data in a loop to return frontCones array?

Here is my code:

```py
# !/usr/bin/python

import rospy

from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from egn_messages.msg import Map
from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion

odometry = Odometry()
map = Map()


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('test_node')

        rospy.Subscriber('/map1', Map, self.mapCallback)
        rospy.Subscriber('/odometry', Odometry, self.odometryCallback)
        self.map = []

        self.carPosX = 0.0
        self.carPosY = 0.0
        self.carPosYaw = 0.0

    def odometryCallback(self, odometry):
        orientation_q = odometry.pose.pose.orientation
        orientation_list = [orientation_q.x, orientation_q.y,
                            orientation_q.z, orientation_q.w]
        (roll, pitch, yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(orientation_list)
        self.carPosX = odometry.pose.pose.position.x
        self.carPosY = odometry.pose.pose.position.y
        self.carPosYaw = yaw

    def mapCallback(self, map):
        self.map = map

    def SampleTree(self):
        if not self.map:
            print
            'map is empty, return'
            return

        frontConesDist = 12
        frontCones = self.getFrontConeObstacles(frontConesDist)
        print(frontCones)

    def getFrontConeObstacles(self, frontDist):
        if not map:
            return []

        headingVector = [1.0, 0]

        behindDist = 0.5
        carPosBehindPoint = [self.carPosX - behindDist * headingVector[0], self.carPosY - behindDist * headingVector[1]]

        frontDistSq = frontDist ** 2

        frontConeList = []
        for cone in map.cones:
            if (headingVectorOrt[0] * (cone.y - carPosBehindPoint[1]) - headingVectorOrt[1] * (
                    cone.x - carPosBehindPoint[0])) < 0:
                if ((cone.x - self.carPosX) ** 2 + (cone.y - self.carPosY) ** 2) < frontDistSq:
                    frontConeList.append(cone)
        return frontConeList


if __name__ == "__main__":
    inst = Test()
    inst.SampleTree()
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, since you're not calling `SampleTree` method at all. But in general. you might want to add `rospy.Timer` with its own callback method and check whether you've received map and odometry message there.

Comment: Just a rough idea: you can try to set a bool variable inside the callbacks, to note when they are invoked and got vail data. Then call SampleTree only when these are true and reset afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry for my incorrect question. The fact is these lines is just a chunk of code and I took a wrong example to describe my issue. I've fixed my code and question to make it clearer. Actually the SampleTree function itself is called in a separate .py file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the values are actually updating in self.map Check by printing new map information in your callback function.

Also add :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__"():
    inst = Test()
    inst.SampleTree()
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
```

rospy.spin() will execute the code in an infinite loop unless interrupted.

Suggestion:

You can name the function

```
def getFrontConeObstacles(self, frontDist):
```

instead of

```
def getFrontConeObstacles(self, map, frontDist):
```

As you can access self.map in the class easily.

Comment: I've changed my code in this question a little again to remove a few errors as well as followed you recomendations, but SampleTree function still doesn't take published data for getFrontConeObstacles function. (output: map is empty, return).

I'm running two publishers. One of them sends custom array containing float64 x and float64 y as Map. Also I'm sending Odometry message as second publisher and then I'm running the subscriber with code provided above. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting output from the map when you are running $ rostopic echo /map1    in the terminal ?

Comment: Yes, I see all messages published to /map1 and /odometry